# Upgrading to Xcode 5.0.2: xib warning. Attribute Unavailable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, xib

I recently upgraded to xcode 5.0.2

Now, I'm getting this warning when I build my Cocoa app:

Attribute Unavailable
Use Current Width For Max Layout Width on Mac OS X version prior to 10.8

I tried to locate 'Max Layout Width' but I wasn't able to.

How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 10):

In Xcode 5.1, uncheck the "First Runtime Layout Width" checkbox in the `NSTextField`'s attributes inspector to remove the warning.

Answer (score 7):

markhunte's answer should give you the background, but in my case there simply wasn't a checkbox for Use First Layout Width As Max for any of my controls. However, in the .xib one text label had:

```
setsMaxLayoutWidthAtFirstLayout="YES"
```

Setting it to NO gets rid of the warning.

Comment: that's right. i had the same problem. it should be officially allowed to re-ask xcode and iphone related questions every 3 months. because an answer that is older than 3 months tends to be outdated in many cases - at least for the questions I am interested in.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is due to "Auto Layout"

> Auto Layout is a system that lets you lay out your app’s user
>   interface by creating a mathematical description of the relationships
>   between the elements

You can Turn it off. But I think if you already upgraded the .xib to use the new xcode 5 IB. Then you may still get the warnings.

You can turn off "Use First Layout as Width as Max" which may be all you need to do.
If you click on one of the warnings it will take you to the element with the issue. In the Inspector you may see:

[image]

which you can uncheck.

---

To turn it off **Autolayout**:

Select your .xib file in the Project Navigator.

[image]

And in the **Identity and Type** Inspector.

Uncheck "Use Autolayout"

[image]

---

But it may be better to look at the Apple Doc for   [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
and Particularly  read  [Adopting Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH15-SW1) which should help you to adjust your project ( I actually need to read this myself :-)  )

Comment: it just resulted in more warnings :-)

Comment: Which part. There is more than one thing. Have you just tried turning the individual Use First Layout as Width as Max. Also what elements/objects are you getting the warnings for –

Comment: Totally missed that one. I guess I was reading your answer too fast. I'll try again and return with the results. Thank you! :-)

Comment: In a window which already had "Use Autolayout" off, the first answer, turning off "Use First Layout as Width as Max", in *all* text fields, worked for me too.  I *think* I know what this means … it should no effect if auto layout is not in use.  But I cannot find a precise definition of it in Xcode documentation.  Whatever it is, my window still works, and this stupid warning which I've been staring at for 3 months is now gone.  Possibly this "bug" occurs if Autolayout is switched off later?  Thanks, markhunte!

Comment: Correction on the suspected pathology.  In a window which is not using Autolayout, add a new text field from the Library.  In its Size inspector, the checkbox "Use First Layout as Width as Max" is switched ON by default.  Boom.  Warning.