# warning: Attribute Unavailable: Tint Color

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

```
file://localhost/Users/.../mYGalleryView.xib: warning: Attribute Unavailable: Tint Color is not available on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

&

```
/Users/.../myCell.xib:9: Letter Spacing Adjustment on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

**warning: Attribute Unavailable:**

**1. Tint Color is not available on iOS versions prior to 6.0**

**2. Letter Spacing Adjustment on iOS versions prior to 6.0**

I am getting warning in the .xib

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054961/how-can-i-fix-freeform-size-simulated-metrics-are-not-available-prior-to-xcode) suggests to change the "Project Development Target" in "File Inspector". of xib file, which is already set to 5.0 as iOS 5.0 is supported.

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103606/upgrading-to-xcode-5-0-2-xib-warning-attribute-unavailable) say to unselect the "AutoLayout" in "File Inspector". I tried that but it didn't work.

What should be done to resolve this warning and also support iOS 5?

Thanks!

Comment: To suppress the warning, while supporting ios5, don't use tint color, and don't use tighten letter spacing. these **do not** exist in ios5...

Comment: @Raz How to uncheck tint color, currently its blue(default) selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove the warning?

Uncheck the corresponding checkmark in the .xib file.

> How to support iOS 6?

You can set them using code. First check whether you can, if yes, set it.

```
if ([self.discountListTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
    self.discountListTableView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
if ([self.titleLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth)]) {
    self.titleLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi @sunkehappy, Is there any way to support both from xib instead of .m?

Comment: As far as I know, no way only using .xib file. Sorry.

Comment: Hi @Sunkehappy, How to uncheck for tint color?